# File name with Scanner Java

Tags: java, file, file-io, io, java.util.scanner

I have successfully been able to type in a file name and get it to output in the console. My only question is why do I have to type in the entire file path:

```
C:\Users\Alek\IdeaProjects\Project1\src\Input1.txt
```

to get the contents of the file displayed to the output? Why can't I just type:

```
Input1.txt
```

to display the contents of the file? Here is the part of the code that handles this task.

```
// Initialize variables
    Scanner keyboard  = new Scanner(System.in);     // Create Scanner object

    // Prompting user for the text file
    System.out.print("Enter the source path to the text file: ");
    String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
    File file = new File(fileName); // Create File object
```

Comment: @JacobG. The text file and the code are in the root directory. I am completely stumped as to why it isn't working.

Comment: They're not.  Your text file is in the `src` folder when it should be located in the `Project1` folder, as seen in my answer below.

Comment: @JacobG. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type just the name of the file if it's in the root directory of the project.

Move `Input1.txt` to its parent folder, so it's absolute path becomes: `C:\Users\Alek\IdeaProjects\Project1\Input1.txt`

Now, you should be able to type the name of the file rather than it's path.